# How to print the bounded type inferred by the compiler when using Generic types?

Tags: java, generics, type-inference, jls, parameterized-types

Consider the following snippet:

```java
List<Exception> exceptionList = Arrays.asList(new Exception("344"));
List<Error> errorList = Arrays.asList(new Error("44"));

//consider a hypothetical function that can print the generic string corresponding
//to the type inferred by the following operation
showType((a == 4) ? exceptionList : errorList);
```

- Here I was wondering if there is some way by which I can write a **function that can print the Generic string corresponding to the type inferred by the compiler** for the above operation?
- eg: I feel that the type inferred must be something like `List<? extends Throwable>` by the compiler - I might be wrong as well **but want to know how can we determine the inferred type by the compiler?**

Comment: `javac --debug=verboseResolution=all`

Comment: What do you mean by "how can we determine the inferred type by the compiler"? Are you asking for a way to determine it programmatically, or in an IDE, or how to work this out mentally?

Comment: @Sweeper good point, I assumed too much from the question.

Comment: @Sweeper - here I mean determining it programatically - something like Generic String function.

Comment: Well you can't do that because of type erasure. All you can get at runtime is `List`, not `List<? extends Throwable>`. You can only get it at compile time(, or prior to that).

Comment: @Sweeper : ok .. how can that be done - just asking this so that anytime I want  to verify my inference against the rules of Java?